# Unable connect to docker container outside docker host

Tags: hadoop, docker

I have two docker containers running on ubuntu , one of them is for hadoop namenode , and another one for hadoop datanode .

Now I have my java code running on windows use Hadoop FileSystem api to copy a file from my windows filesystem to remote docker hdfs .

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;

public class HadoopTest {

    @Test
    public void testCopyFileToHDFS() throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addResource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hadoop/core-site.xml"));
        configuration.addResource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hadoop/yarn-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
        FileUtil.copy(new File("c:\\windows-version.txt"),fileSystem,   new Path("/testsa"), false,configuration);
    }
}
```

but I got the following error:

```
16:57:05.669 [Thread-4] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Connecting to datanode 172.18.0.2:50010
16:57:15.654 [IPC Client (547201549) connection to /192.168.56.102:9000 from ignis] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (547201549) connection to /192.168.56.102:9000 from ignis: closed
16:57:15.655 [IPC Client (547201549) connection to /192.168.56.102:9000 from ignis] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - IPC Client (547201549) connection to /192.168.56.102:9000 from ignis: stopped, remaining connections 0
16:57:26.670 [Thread-4] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
16:57:26.673 [Thread-4] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Abandoning BP-53577818-172.18.0.2-1500882061263:blk_1073741827_1003
```

You can see the first line error which says **"Connecting to datanode 172.18.0.2:50010"** is a docker internal ip address.

My Java code is running on a real  windows machine which is outside of the docker host machine.

I have mapped Hadoop HDFS ports (e.g. 9000 and 50010) to my docker host(ubuntu).So I can access the HDFS name node through docker host ip address and the HDFS's port.

Below are the logic of my java code:

1)Java Code is running on windows Machine

2)Java code use FileSystem api to copy file from windows to remote HDFS.

3)The client can connect to HDFS name node by using docker host's Ip address and ports mapped from docker container (e.g. 9000)

4)HDFS Namenode server will handle the request send from client and return data node's ip address to client.

5)Client try to copy file from local by use the data node's ip address

6)Client got the error which said the data node's ip address can not be access ,because it's a ip address inside docker container

[image]

Comment: Where is your Java code running then? Why can't you map the ports for these two services to the host?

Comment: Please have a look at my updates .

Comment: Why not you try that you java code that point to ```192.168.1.25:50010```, you should enable port in your docker container.  For example ```docker run -p 50010:50010```

Comment: Not a hadoop expert. But can you config `NameNode` to return `192.168.1.25:50010` as `DataNode` access ip address? Or Is there a tool can act as proxy before `NameNode` and `DataNode`, providing HTTP API server all by itself, instead of rediect this way?

Comment: No ,I can't point to 192.168.1.25:50010 directly  , because 172.18.0.2:50010 is return by name node docker container .

Comment: I think the application should be connecting to `localhost:50010`? Because port 50010 of your machine is mapped to the docker container's 50010.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I found solution by introduce hostname for datanode  and enable hdfs client to use hostname instead of ip address when connect to datanode,my client also need to map datanode  hostname as docker host ip address, below are detail steps:

1. Add hostname for docker datanode container in docker-compose.xml

   **hostname: datanode.company.com**
2. Enable hdfs (server & client) to use hostname instead of ip address.

```js
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

1. Map docker datanode hostname as docker host ip address by add an entry in file of etc/hosts

   192.168.1.25  datanode.company.com

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me out.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do you consume this docker-compose.xml file to connect to hdfs?

Comment: can you please help me in connecting to hdfs running in docker outside the container?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this without adding hostname for datanode container. I run hadoop on a local docker container, so my example will be with localhost, change it to your docker accessable external address.

If you are trying to write files into hdfs inside docker container, here what happens:

1. new FileSystem.get(configuration) connects to namenode configured in **core-site.xml** with `fs.defaultFS` property:

```
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
    </property>
```

2. Namenode responses with datanode hostname, where to upload data. It is configured with **hdfs-site.xml** property `dfs.datanode.hostname` - accessable docker external address:

```
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.hostname</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>
```

My hostname is localhost for local docker container

3. Client new FileSystem.get(configuration) connects to namenode and retrieves datanode host to upload data to. It is configured with:

```
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    // Namenode connection on local docker container
    configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfs://localhost:9000);
    // Configure client to ask namenode for datanode hostname to upload data
    configuration.setBoolean("dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname", true);
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
```

configuration properties description: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml